# How do I change the blank template in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have created a new template for Excel 2007 and placed in it the `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` Book.

This has worked successfully in that when you open Excel it uses this file. However, it does not work when I use the Open/New/Blank command. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong folder. You need to save the template to the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\XLStart` folder. Files in this folder will be opened when Excel starts.

```
To create a default workbook, enter book.xltx.

To create a default worksheet, enter sheet.xltx.
```

Make sure you use the **`Save As`** function and select **`Excel Template (*.xltx)`** when saving.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-default-theme-3b0d77d4-9d33-4bd2-91f9-d95ce39c66b3)